# How can I upgrade a package without removing its dependencies?

Tags: upgrade, aptitude

For some reason (having used `xorg-edgers` in the past might be part of that), I still have a very old X server installed:

```
xorg   7.6+7ubuntu7.1
xserver-xorg-core  1.10.4-1ubuntu4.2
xserver-xorg-video-intel  2.16.0+git20111011.823a4272-0ubuntu0sarvatt~natty
```

when I try `dist-upgrade`, `aptitude` wants to remove 255 packages first (`acrobat`, `bluez-alsa`, ..., `ia32-libs`, ..., `xserver-xorg-video-`* to name a few)

Is there a way to update packages forcing Ubuntu to ignore any dependencies it might think that could theoretically be violated?

On a RPM-based system, I'd use `rpm --force --nodeps`

Note: I already removed the xorg-edgers ppa.

Note 2: I'm trying to upgrade with `aptitude safe-upgrade` and `aptitude dist-upgrade`

Comment: Forcing to ignore dependencies is always a bad idea as I have just experienced from the systems in my lab. Unless you are sure what you are doing, don't do it.

Comment: Well, I'm 100% sure Ubuntu is getting it wrong so what options do I have? I could probably download the source packages and rebuild them without dependencies ...

Comment: Brrr.. This is sending a shiver down my spine. I believe it is best to wait for an expert opinion on this. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `aptitude` contains new code to resolve dependencies. This code is ... [could be better](https://www.google.ch/search?q=aptitude%20bugs%20resolver). :-)

In my case, running `apt-get upgrade` just offered to upgrade the 13 xorg packages and leave the rest of my system alone.

So if your `aptitude` hangs itself in the dependency graph (= when installing/upgrading, it wants to remove hundreds of packages first), give the old tools another try.

Answer (score 0):

Only way i know for holding is using `aptitude`, where you can set packages to hold. The only problem is, that you should further use aptitude for every updating/installing/removing task, because AFAIK other package manager tools does not care about hold-flags. In `apt-get` docs is also option `--ignore-hold`, but at least last time i used `apt-get` with hold-flags set to some packages, it ignored them anyway.